# Show that $(f+g)_{\ast}=f_{\ast}+g_{\ast}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, higher-homotopy-groups

I have the following problem:

Let $X$ be some (path-connected) topological space. I have to show that for two $f,g\in\pi_{n}(X)$ we have that $(f+g)_{\ast}=f_{\ast}+g_{\ast}$, where $\ast$ denotes the induced homomorphism on the singular homology $H_{n}(X)$.

In the lecture, we have defined $\pi_{n}(X,x_{0})$ using spheres, so $f,g$ are functions $f,g:S^{n}\to X$ such that $f(s_{0})=g(s_{0})=x_{0}$. The group operation $f+g$ is then defined to be the composition

$$S^{n}\to S^{n}\vee S^{n}\to X$$

The first map, lets denote it by $\psi$, collapses the equator $S^{n-1}$ in $S^{n}$ to a point and where the second map takes the first sphere in the wedge sum via $f$ to $X$ and the second sphere via $g$ to $X$.

How to I show the claimed equation on homology?

Comment: Perhaps this is not as satisfactory as an answer as you would like, but this is proved in Prop 4.36 of Hatcher's algebraic topology book. He proves the relative case, but you can just do the absolute case by replacing all instances of $A$ in his proof with the empty set.

Comment: You have an isomorphism $\widetilde H_*(S^n\vee S^n)\cong\widetilde H_*S^n\oplus \widetilde H_*S^n$. You need to show that with respect to this isomorphism, $\psi$ induces the diagonal map $\alpha\mapsto (\alpha,\alpha)$. Then $(f+g)_*=(f,g)_*\psi_*$ is the map $\alpha\mapsto (\alpha,\alpha)\mapsto f_*\alpha+g_*\alpha$.

Comment: Okay thank you...I think I got the idea. Short question: Why is this an isomorphism?

Comment: It is the *additivity axiom*.